# A counter that decreases by 1,000 every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

Hello guys I have searched high and low for something like this.

So for example:

starting number 100,000

decreases to 99,000 after 5 minutes

thanks for all the help.

Comment: Then surely you have found something to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See bellow example :

Decrease by 1 seconde :

```js
var number = 100000;
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  number-= 3.333333333333;
  number = Math.round(number);
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = number;
  console.log("number equals " +number +" - in " + (++i)+ "seconde");
},1000);
```

```css
h3 {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Counter : </h3>
<span id="counter">100000<span>
```

decrease by 5 min :

```js
var number = 100000;
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  number-= 1000;
  console.log("number equals " +number );
},1000*60*5);
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for this. I am having trouble making this show in a html file. Can you help me?

Comment: see my answer just add your html and above the html open <script type="text/javascript"> write here above js code the colse </script>

Answer (score 1):

```
var count=100000;
setInterval(function(){
  count-=1000;
},1000*60*5);
```